# Why is object.__getattr__ missing?

Tags: python

Why does `object` seem not to have a `__getattr__` method?  It defines both `__setattr__` and `__delattr__`.  Doesn't it need all three?

```
>>> object.__setattr__
<slot wrapper '__setattr__' of 'object' objects>
>>> 
>>> object.__delattr__
<slot wrapper '__delattr__' of 'object' objects>
>>> 
>>> object.__getattr__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'object' has no attribute '__getattr__'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 19:58:35) \n[GCC 4.6.3]'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indeed, `object` does not have a `__getattr__` method.

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dir(object))
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

Instead, it has `__getattribute__`.

```
>>> object.__getattribute__
<slot wrapper '__getattribute__' of 'object' objects>
```

[`https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) explains why:

> `object.__getattribute__(self, name)`
>
> > Called unconditionally to implement attribute accesses for instances of the class. If the class also defines `__getattr__()`, the latter will not be called unless `__getattribute__()` either calls it explicitly or raises an `AttributeError`.

In other words, if you have `__getattribute__`, it doesn't make sense to also define `__getattr__`.

Historically, `__getattr__` came first, and `__getattribute__` was introduced with "new-style classes" in Python 2.3 (iirc).  Python 3 only has new-style classes but seems to have preserved both hooks anyway (perhaps because it can be convenient to have a hook that is *only* called if "normal attribute access" fails).

Comment: `__getattr__` is typically used for computed attributes. For instance, [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) uses `__getattr__` when accessing attributes of a mocked object.

Comment: @Dunes: That or `@property`/descriptors.  It all depends on what precise effect you're trying to create.

Comment: So, how did you solve what Ankur Agarwal described?

Comment: @just_learning Either the answer is "a class that defines `__getattribute__` does not need to define `__getattr__`" or I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, as I see better the question I see that my problem is not so similar to this question! Thanks anyway... I will open a new thread!

Answer (score 3):

[`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) is a method that runs only after [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__). Since `object` has the latter, there is technically no need for the former. But in general, you shouldn’t expect `object` to have all the things that other objects (deriving from it) have. Since `object` is implemented in native code, it may behave a bit differently.

Comment: Most of all, `__getattr__` is optional, `__setattr__`, `__delattr__` and  `__getattribute__` are not.