# Catch-all method in class that passes all unknown functions to instance in class

Tags: python, methods, catch-all

I want to forward all of the unknown functions in my own class definition to an object in that class. One could directly access the object in the class, but was wondering if there is a pythonic way to pass all of the methods that belong to this object directly. Look at it as a 'catch-all' for methods or passthrough.

Tried **getattr** but failed to get it to do exactly what I want it to do.

```py
class MyClass(): 

   def __init__(self, name, object): 
         self.name = name
         self.object = object

   def known_function(self): 
         return '{}_blabla'.format(self.name) 

   def all_unknown_functions(self): 
         return self.object.thisunknownfunction()
```

Want: all of the unknown functions to pass through to the object inside my class, without me having to re-define all of these functions.

edit: the getattr method would be the same as the all_unknown_functions method
edit2: fixed the parameter in known_function

Comment: what do you mean with *unknown functions* ?

Comment: You mention that you tried `__getattr__`, but it failed. Can you elaborate what you exactly tried and why it failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `__getattr__` and add your `self.object` search logic for missing attribute there:

```
class MyClass():  
    def __init__(self, name, obj):  
        self.name = name 
        self.obj = obj 

    def known_function(self, name):  
        return '{}_blabla'.format(name) 

    def __getattr__(self, attr): 
        if attr not in self.__dict__: 
            return getattr(self.obj, attr) 
        return super().__getattr__(attr) 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    
m = MyClass('foo', str)                                                                                                                                                                            
    
m.lower                                                                                                                                                                                            
# <method 'lower' of 'str' objects>
    
m.known_function('spam')                                                                                                                                                                           
# 'spam_blabla'
```

Here we're checking if the `attr` is in the instance dict, if not we get the attribute from `self.obj`.

Note that, this will get any attribute, not only a function. You can add a `types.MethodType` check later.

---

Also, you've referred the name `name` in `known_function`, which does not exist in the local scope, you presumably meant to take a `name` argument or
use `self.name`.

---

**Edit:**

Actually `__getattr__` is called last in the attribute lookup chain, so you can drop the check for `self.__dict__` as this check *has been done earlier* already, so do:

```
class MyClass(): 
    def __init__(self, name, obj):  
        self.name = name 
        self.obj = obj 
    def known_function(self, name):  
        return '{}_blabla'.format(name) 

    def __getattr__(self, attr): 
        return getattr(self.obj, attr)
```

Comment: also we could use `try: return self.__getattribute__(name) except: return self.object.__getattribute__(name)`

Comment: very sensible answer. Good to show that you can adjust the search logic to point to an underlying object.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Check my edits. We can actually drop the `self.__dict__` check.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on this question while implementing a decorator. Putting it here for future reference:

```
class Decorator():
    def __init__(self, seed):
        self._seed = seed

    def decorated(self):
        return self

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self._seed.__getattribute__(attr)
```

Python3 has hooks for both  `__getattr__` but only `__getattribute__` is present by default ([Why is object.__getattr__ missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530982/why-is-object-getattr-missing))